# Styling photos in slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I have this very simple slideshow here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/11/
Here's the codes:
HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M0US5a4.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Akqe7Hm.png">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/X2IfizW.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 300px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

As you can see in the slideshow the pictures is very wide and have large width and height, and it goes off the slideshow box frames.
I'm trying to add a code that CUTS the photo so it goes exactly in the frames of the slideshow box, for example, the photo should be like that:
[image]

What I have tried to do is to add `width: auto` or `height: auto` but it wasn't what I need.

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/12/

Comment: That's really good but how can I take control of the photo so I can center the photo or change the position of the view to any other position(I think it should be with background position?)

Comment: you can prevent it from cutting it out but for that you have to give the fixed witdh and height for images in slideshow which will eventually leads to this http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add overflow hidden

```
#slideshow > div {
    ...
    overflow:hidden;
    ...
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/10/)

**Update**

As per OP request ""

first you need to change your img tag to a div

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <div class="imgLike" style="background-image: url('http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg'); background-position:center; "></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <div class="imgLike" style="background-image: url('http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg'); background-position:center; "></div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div class="imgLike" style="background-image: url('http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png'); background-position:center; "></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

next you will need this class

```
.imgLike {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/17/)

The [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) property will allow you to center or offset by number the image

Comment: Can I ask you another question? How can I take control of the photo so I can center the photo or change the position of the view to any other position(I think it should be with background position?)

Comment: @System-x32z oops had an extra closing tag, try now

Comment: man you did it, thank you very much for that, upvote, accepted, really thank you